# How to customize custom field of magic field plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to specify product features under product page.

Like

```
DIMENSIONS (title)
Width x Height x Depth (with stand)  --     902 mm x 563 mm x 204 mm
width --- 902mm

General(title)
Brand  -  Vu
Display Size  - 102
```

these details will change based on products. How I can add these kind of options using wordpress magic filed plugin. For adding products I have used magic field plugin. Can I use the same plugin for doing these kind of functionality

For any help advance thank you